# Multiple AWS accounts assuming an IAM role for API gateway access

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles, amazon-iam

We have an API gateway having some APIs exposed. To give other AWS account to provide an acccess, we are using an IAM role way, i.e. we created an IAM role in our account with other AWS account id in trust policy which other AWS account can assume. Now, if I want to add more AWS account to this policy in same role and then they can assume this role. Is that okay to do by practice? Or should we create new role for each new AWS account id? Which is a better way to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a separate role for each customer (account) but you should make sure that you are handling external IDs correctly.

For each of your customers, you should create external ID that is shared only between you and that particular customer to prevent confused deputy problem.

Once you have set up external IDs with all of your customers, you can modify the role's trust policy to include separate statement for each of your customers, where you are checking whether it is a trusted principal (account id) and whether the corresponding external ID has been passed as an argument to `sts:assumeRole` call.

Suppose that you have a role that can be assumed by two customers. First account 's id is `1111` and external ID for that customer is `aaaa`. Second account's id is `2222` and external ID for that customer is `bbbb`. Your trust policy should look like this.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1111:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "aaaa"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2222:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "bbbb"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that you probably want to use GUIDs for external IDs, not `aaaa` or `bbbb`.